# Text Losses After Committing using JSON

Tags: json, git, github

I am developing an application using React Native, and currently working on to translate texts using JSON. The JSON file is a language translation file. It's to store text strings in different languages for internationalization purposes. Here's what the contents represent:

```
  {
  "Messages": "Beskeder",
  "Calendar": "Kalender",
  "Cancel": "Annullér",
  ....
  {
```

However, for some reason, some of my texts are being deleted after I have committed. Why does this happen? It's only 4-5 texts that are being deleted after the commit the rest 100+ works just fine, what could be the reason for that?

I am using Github Desktop to commit, and been using it for years now. Haven't had this problem before, and I am just stuck, and do not know what to do. I also checked if I have any merge conflicts using git status command, and I do not have any merge conflicts.

Comment: Do you have any `CI/CD` pipelines configurations? I guess please also reconfirm that all the text have been saved - which should not be difficult to check as you can view file changes directly in `Github Desktop`.